# Auto Flex the Overlapping Div to new Row with same margin-left

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have [3 Span Blocks (which may be "n" number)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEu8y.jpg)  with some left margin for each in a container;
The problem is if I style them using **position: absolute** these spans are getting overlapped. On the other hand, Then are showing right when I don't use the absolute position as each block will have its own line. 
I can't show each of them in a new line. I just need to shift or push the overlapped span into a new line and anything else which is not overlapped needs to be shown in the space wherever possible without hindering the left margin.

Please advise or help me out of this situation.

```css
.sp{
margin:2px;
height:20px;
border-radius:5px;

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
opacity:0.7;
}


.sp2{
margin:2px;
height:20px;
border-radius:5px;
position:absolute;

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;border:1px solid brown">
        <div style="background-color: red;width:300px;margin-left:30px" class="sp">DIV 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:bisque;width:230px;margin-left:100px" class="sp">DIV 2</div>
        <div style="background-color:rgb(236, 135, 135);width:180px;margin-left:400px" class="sp">DIV 3</div>
 </div>
 
 
 
 
 <h1>SECOND RESULT</h1>
 
<div style="width: 100%;border:1px solid brown">
        <div style="background-color: red;width:300px;margin-left:30px" class="sp2">DIV 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:bisque;width:230px;margin-left:100px" class="sp2">DIV 2</div>
        <div style="background-color:rgb(236, 135, 135);width:180px;margin-left:400px" class="sp2">DIV 3</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please share your code so that we can understand your situation in a better way.

Comment: @Nil Hi I have added the code.